# Tableau multiselect filter behavior with no items selected

Tags: tableau-api

I have a problem where I want a multiselect filter, but I don't want the user to be able to deselect all items. Here's what I'm doing, focusing on the "Geography" filter:

[image: View with at least one county]

If I deselect all the counties from the filter, the entire map and chart disappear off the dashboard!

[image: View with all counties deselected]

It seems like there are various options that would work in this situation. One option would be for the map background to remain (with just no counties overlaid); I don't know what the chart would show. Better yet would be to somehow disallow deselecting that final value so at least one value must always be selected. But having the viz just disappear doesn't seem like a very friendly behavior.

Comment: One workaround would be to have another version of the map sitting below the current one, that has default view of whatever you choose, then if the user does de-select all regions they would see the default map. You could even add a message to this map to prompt them to select at least one region.

Comment: That's an interesting solution. I hate how everything with Tableau seems to be workarounds. I'll see if anything else shows up. Thanks!